# How to write a tree structure lookup query in MariaDB mybatis environment

Tags: database, mariadb, database-administration

I want to send a query to the tree structure table in the mariadb environment.

The desired results are as follows.
`[{"no":7,"name":null,"parentNo":null,"childList":[]} .....]`

Below is mybatis code.
`

```
<select id="selectSubList" resultMap="testMap">
    SELECT
        no,
        name
    FROM
        test
    WHERE
        parent_no = #{no}

</select>


<select id="selectList" resultMap="testMap">
    SELECT
        no,
        name
    FROM
        test
    WHERE
        parent_no IS NULL
</select>
```

`
Can you implement this as a recursive query?

And I'm wondering which one is better, my method or the performance of recursive queries

I'm worried about the performance because they told me to avoid nested select on the official website of mybatis.
Thank you.

Comment: Fixed or dynamic number of levels? Should be trivial with a join, CTE, or even with `<collection>`s. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.